# selenium chromedriver driver.get() timeout due to websocket on page

Tags: node.js, selenium, websocket, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium chromedriver in nodejs to write some end-to-end tests.

When loading "myurl", the command `await driver.get("myurl")` always timeouts.
In network I see that there is a websocket (appcues) which continues (status "pending").

I assume that selenium thinks there is still things to load, but the page is already loaded, it takes 2 seconds to load the whole page, except that the websocket is still running.

Is there a way to use `driver.get()` and specify to ignore explicit requests to be finished ? (since the websocket will never stop).

Comment: may you can try once pageloadtime out with few seconds and handling exceptions if throws..https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: The thing is that I would like to avoid having to catch the exception. Yes I think it could work, but I would be afraid that it's the "best" solution ...

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. Once it has reached the timeout, any other call to `driver.*` will throw the same exception "TimeoutError: timeout".

Comment: You can try setting capability  'pageLoadStrategy' to 'eager' (Supported in Chromedriver 77 https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt) https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-table-of-page-load-strategies

Comment: Thanks a lot @RahulL . I set pageLoadStrategy to `none` since chromedriver 77 isn't released yet on npm, and it worked :) You can write an answer and I will validate it. This seems to be an important thing to know about selenium, in order to test pages with websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pageLoadStrategy capability [Documentation WeDriver-W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-table-of-page-load-strategies)

"none"  -  none causes command to return immediately

"eager" - eager causes command to return after the DOMContentLoaded event fires.

"normal" - The normal state causes command to return after the load event fires on the new page

```
 let driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
.withCapabilities({ 'pageLoadStrategy': 'none' }) 
.forBrowser('chrome') 
.build()
```

Note : eager is supported in [Chromedriver 77](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt)

Comment: You can add this too : `let driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities({
      'pageLoadStrategy': 'none'
    })
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build()` as an example for nodejs ;)